# Role of algebraic topology in number theory or algebraic geometry

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics

I am an undergraduate student, broadly interested in number theory and algebraic geometry. As group cohomology and related things are an integral part of modern number theory and algebraic geometry, I decided to take a course on graduate algebraic topology in my current semester. This course covered singular homology and cohomology theory. But I fared quite badly in the course and got a bad grade. I also feel like I have not learnt much from the course.
How much could this hurt my future endeavours in number theory or algebraic geometry? Secondly, how much could this hurt my chances of getting accepted for grad school?

P.S.: I am pretty comfortable with basic point-set topology, fundamental groups, covering spaces etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had similar worries when I was an undergrad; I had to quit the graduate alg top course because it was too difficult, and so I sympathize with your question.  While I have amounted to essentially nothing in math research despite great ambitions (I'm not even at Ph.D. granting institution) and perhaps you probably should dismiss my opinion, I'm writing this answer perhaps as much for me as for you: after 20 years of working my way up the academic ladder (mid0-career at the moment - associate prof with minimal publications at a primarily undergraduate teaching focused institution, which have come to love), I wish I go back and tell myself: You are worrying too much and focusing on the wrong things. Just enjoy learning/doing math, do your best, and live with the results, whatever they are.  That being said, if you are challenging yourself by taking graduate courses as an undergrad, and most of your record in math courses is strong, you should be able to get into a middle-tier R1 at the very least (I'm only familiar with the U.S., though)...albeit that's my sense based on the last time at a Ph.D. granting place (low ranked R1) about 10 years ago, and I don't know if getting into Ph.D. pure math programs have gotten harder or easier.

I should be get back to some administrative/committee work I'm avoiding so I leave with a disorganized hodge-podge of links/comments:

See the following article for a Princeton professor June Huh that who had a negative initial experience in math, was rejected initially by the grad school (top 5 in algebra/number theory according to this list https://www.usnews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-science-schools/number-theory-rankings) where he eventually got his Ph.D. from, and used cohomology to solve a big open problem in combinatorics.

https://www.quantamagazine.org/a-path-less-taken-to-the-peak-of-the-math-world-20170627/

I agree with another answer that many mathematicians need multiple exposures to difficult topics like cohomology.  "One doesn't understand math one just gets used to it" (von Neumann quote).

Regarding algebraic topology and algebraic geometry:

- "It was my lot to plant the harpoon of algebraic topology into the body of the whale of algebraic geometry." - Solomon Lefschetz
- 2 min video of Jacob Lurie on algebraic topology and algebraic geometry/number theory (mentioning Weil conjectures) https://youtu.be/qHwjG5611V4
- there are entire industries involving both e.g. motivic homotopy theory, derived algebraic geometry.
- The topic of cohomology is vast - there is singular, sheaf, etale, generalized cohomologies (K-theory, Morava E-theories), prismatic, De Rham, crystalline, Dolbeault, syntomic, rigid, and new ones will continue to be invented ... and it is impossible to learn it all, and you don't need to have done well in algebraic topology 1 (or arguably, even remember small details ... IMO the main ideas, conceptual breakthroughs, and big picture are more important)  to dip ones toes into exploring these topics. Instead one has to learn and relearn (a phrase I borrowed from Terry Tao's blog) topics, and if your research problems leads you to need to learn algebraic topology more carefully, then there will be motivation and the perspective of your problem to learn it. (Ok, you may have to learn it to pass through quals ... but can usually get by those by looking at past problems identify the small number of concepts/patterns that are "tested")

As Churchill said, success is going from failure to failure without loss of enthusiasm. For most mathematicians, there are some topics in math one enjoys/understands and others that just aren't their cup of tea.

Every now and then on twitter, there is a "what is cohomology" discussion or dare I say meme:

"Be kind, for everyone you meet is fighting to understand what cohomology is. #inspirationaltopology" at
https://twitter.com/evelynjlamb/status/639087415605526529

and here is a tweet that express confusion with cohomology, and one of the responses is a nice thread giving an overview
https://twitter.com/bathematician/status/1247556791870734336

Answer (score 4):

I won't speak to your chances of getting into graduate school, because that does depend a lot on the school, and on how highly ranked a program you are considering.

The job market for academic jobs in theoretical mathematics is terrible, with far more highly qualified candidates than permanent positions, especially (but not only) for permanent positions with research responsibilities.  If you are a Fields Medal candidate, then you can still find a job easily.  If you are merely very good, you have reasonable chances, but you might not find a job.  If you are merely good, your chances aren't so good.  There are no reasons to expect the situation to improve, and it might get worse.

Now if you really want to do mathematics, then you really want to do mathematics, and it doesn't matter quite so much what the job prospects are, given that it's possible to go to grad school without incurring (more) debt.

Cohomology theory operates at an extra level of abstraction than all the courses you've likely seen before.  Just as many students find their first course emphasizing proofs quite challenging, many students find their first course at this extra level of abstraction challenging.  Many students have to see this material twice to actually understand it.  At our low-ranked PhD program, where as far as I can tell none of our PhD graduates in theoretical mathematics have gone on to do research of any significance (and most dissertations are not publishable except in a write-only journal), we don't really expect any of our PhD students to ever understand cohomology except perhaps in a special case where we have digested it for them.

However, just as most of the most accomplished mathematicians breezed through their first course emphasizing proofs, most of the most accomplished mathematicians managed to learn algebraic topology the first time.  This is only a correlation; there are accomplished mathematicians who needed two or more tries to understand cohomology.  Nevertheless, failure to learn cohomology the first time is evidence against you.

Cohomology is central in current mainstream research in theoretical mathematics; in some sense its presence defines the mainstream.  (It's not so important in many areas of combinatorics or analysis, but those are not mainstream these days.  It's also almost completely absent in applied mathematics, even the more theoretical parts of applied mathematics.)  You do need to learn it eventually to do any serious number theory or algebraic geometry research, and the algebraic topology setting is for most people the easiest entry point.

Comment: Ha! :) "Write-only journals" took me a minute. :) But, as it happens, the finite-element method in numerical analysis has evolved to used (basic) (co) homological notions! :)  And mirror symmetry is a big deal in both physics and alg geom. But, yes, absolutely, alg top is the most physically intuitive entry point.

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that it'd be better if you'd aced the course, one way or another, you're already "aiming high", so in that case a failure now and then is not surprising, and in the face of a good body of other advanced work will not seriously harm your grad school chances, even at very good places.

To respond to the other aspect of your question: "(co)homology" is indeed at a slightly fancier/more-abstract level than most other undergrad or basic grad math. The most basic form is basic algebraic topology, which should already start things up by simplicial homology, but after wrangling with technical difficulties for a while, introduce simplicial homology. Useful for many things, like (persuasively) proving the Jordan Curve Theorem, etc.

Meanwhile, c. 1930, Emmy Noether and her school organized prior work on algebraic structures and could describe obstructions to various maps, or descriptions of non-commuting, as elements of "cohomology classes", originally defined in a completely ad-hoc way, and not defining $H^i$ for $i$ other than $i=0,1,2$ or at most $3$. (There was no need.)

Somewhat later, DeRham (re)formulated ideas about Gauss-Green-Stokes in cohomological terms...

Cech (and others) had formulated "sheaf cohomology" in a fashion imitating variants of alg top constructions.

To my mind, Grothendieck's realization that *also* sheaf cohomology could be realized as a "derived functor", thus becoming "simply" an example of that basic (co) homological stuff was a major turning point. With hindsight, all the "classical" (co) homology theories are/were derived functors of natural things (like fixed-point or cofixed-point functors, or, for sheaves, the global sections functor).

$K$-theory is somewhat different, as it did not fit into that mold. The low-index $K$-groups arose in meaningful ad-hoc fashions, but/and D. Quillen finally saw (late 1970's) a general pattern.

But/and "general" cohomological stuff is not made easily analogous to the alg top version. The *symbols* often behave similarly, yes, but... "why?" :)

My recommendation to people is to lightly read C. Weibel's "Homological Algebra", in which he goes through many of the standard examples. "Group (co)homology", "Lie algebra (co)homology", etc., are indeed just examples of derived functors of obvious basic functors.

(This in contrast to decades-ago, when trying to learn relevant group cohomology to understand the Artin-Tate classfield notes... the implicit choice of a resolution ("bar" or "homogeneous bar") seemed nutty to me. Oh, ahem, later, I learned that these are just convenient choices of projective or injective resolutions, etc. Whew. And the funkily-named things like "Shapiro's Lemma" are just examples of very general, and not-so-complicated, devices in general (co) homological algebra.)

Comment: Do you have recommendations for how to understand the Artin-Tate notes? Did you read it from beginning to end?

Comment: @cgb5436, no, I did not at all read it straight through! Not by any means! By this year, I might recommend Jim Milne's notes on classfield theory, as an exemplar of a fairly formal, and correct, treatment. Also, the Artin-Tate notes are anachronistic, insofar as they wrote in a style that did not confidently use modern homological algebra (reasonable-enough, considering the time!).

Comment: @cgb5436, also, my own notes on "Number Theory" (at my website, and also at the AMS's free-text site) try to give some motivation for (co) homological description of classfield theory. I don't finally prove the main theorems, but do try to give some motivation for describing things in those terms.

Comment: Thanks. But there doesn't seem to be many other references for things like the Weil group, class formations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, as and undergrad taking grad courses it shouldn't be much of a factor, but every admissions system is different. In my day, even a good understanding of point-set topology would be really advanced, though times have changed.

If this is for grad school in the US no single grade is likely to make a substantial difference and letters of recommendation from your professors are very important.

But, what's done is done. Don't lose sleep over what you can't control. There are a lot of good grad schools at R1 universities that would ignore a single data point if other things point to success.

---

As to the relationship between Algebraic Topology and the other fields mentioned I can't be much help. Algebraic Topology and Algebraic Geometry seem to be asking rather different questions, however. Number Theory, on the other hand is so rich that it is "touched" by many other fields. My knowledge is long out of date, though.

Comment: Your knowledge is long out of date - one of the major themes in current algebraic geometry research is understanding the cohomology - either in the classical singular cohomology sense or in the sense of intersection theory or more exotic cohomology theories (that might apply in positive characteristic) - of algebraic varieties.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo, thanks. The math does flow.